# quantify correlation simultaneously for linear and non-linear trends

Tags: regression, correlation, nonlinear-regression, pearson-r, spearman-rho

### Intro

Consider the following figure:
[image]

The red data is my observed data and the blue data is the simulated data. In an *ideal* case one would expect to *detect* all the data points. However, in real life, this is not the case, hence the difference between the observed and simulated data.

My main interest is to study whether there is a correlation between

1. $x_{obs}$ and $y_{obs}$
2. $x_{sim}$ and $y_{sim}$

and finally

3. I want to compare whether the correlation of the *observed* data is similar to the correlation of the *simulated* data.

### Question

Is there a *single* method that can be used to study my points (1) and (2)? i.e. is there a dependence test that can be used to study linear and non-linear trends?

If yes, then I believe my point (3) can be easily done by simply comparing the strength of the 2 correlations, right?

Can someone please tell me what is the best way to compare the 2 trends?

Comment: I think you need to more clearly explain what the situation is here.

Comment: @Glen_b, can you please be more specific? What information do you need?

Comment: There is no evident connection between the "observed" and "simulated" data.

Comment: @whuber, my main interest is to show that as $x_{obs}$ increases, $y_{obs}$ also increases (which can be seen in the simulated data). How can I quantify this?

Comment: In your comment above, do you mean something like "I want to show that as $x_\text{obs}$ increases, the expectation of $y_\text{obs}$ increases"? Clearly $y_\text{obs}$ itself goes both up and down and you move right.

Comment: @Glen_b, yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: What is $y_\text{obs}$? What is $y_\text{sim}$? How are the two related? Why does the conditional distribution of $y_\text{sim}$ at a specific $x$ appear to be uniform?

Comment: @Glen_b, $y_{obs}$ moves up and down simply because these data are observed and they have uncertainties. So this is not an *ideal* set of data.

Comment: What *IS* $y_\text{obs}$ exactly? What is it you're observing here? How are the $y_\text{sim}$ values obtained? How exactly do the two things relate to each other? What the heck is going on?

Comment: $y_{obs}$ is the radius of detected exoplanets (or planets), hence the uncertainties. And $y_{sim}$ is the radius of a planet according to theory and simulations.

Comment: I expect a correlation between $x$ and $y$ because of theory. This correlation can be seen in the simulated data. Now I am trying to prove that it is there in the observed data. However, not all the planets are detected because smaller planets are more difficult to detect (which is the reason why there's a lack of small sized planets at high $x$'s.

Comment: Both series clearly increase on average with $x$ but this is useless information in terms of judging the suitability of theory, since all manner of functions are increasing. In fact the observed data are clearly larger than the most extreme simulated values, so we're not just dealing with some bias where we observe only the top few percent. See the obvious comparison [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OaraD.png). The observed values are far, far above simulated. In addition, it looks like the average simulated value increases faster than linearly, but there's no indication of that in the data.

Comment: Even without the issues of truncation/bias, why would "similarity of correlation" be remotely meaningful here? I am having trouble coming up with any very meaningful question relating to what you describe that cannot be immediately answered by looking at the plots.

Comment: Surely a suitable investigation would try to identify where theory and observation depart (hint: you'll need a model for the bias toward only observing the larger values).

Comment: @Glen_b, I apologize for the confusion but this is a 'toy model'. This is not the real data. I meant to reproduce the *trends*. My data is far more complicated than the data shown here. And as I've said earlier, my observed data has uncertainties. So I'm figuring out a way to *start* solving this problem and then I'll integrate solving it while incorporating the uncertainties.

Comment: I can't see *any* way to make sense of comparing two correlations in this situation. Saying "but it's a toy model" doesn't make it make more sense.

Comment: What about 2d kolmogorov smirnov test? Then I'll compare the 2 distributions.

Comment: How would that make sense? You have no basis on which to expect them to be the same. Assume your underlying simulated model is right. Your observations are a noisy version of a sort of biased/truncated version of that ... so the distributions will look entirely different. And before you throw more proposals out, they'll all have this problem until you face the fundamental issue that you're not comparing like with like. You have to deal with that in some way.

Comment: So in the end we come down to "what are you really trying to find out?"

Comment: @Glen_b, I changed the figure, I hope the data makes more sense now. And yes, the model I am using *IS* correct. It has been used/published since 2009. It successfully reproduces well-known observed correlations. The discrepancies in this case are mainly due to detection bias. Please let me know if further information is required.

Comment: "Reproduces observed correlations" is in no way a reason to think the model is correct, unless you have a basis to relate simulated to observed that would leave you comparing like with like; by the same token, very different correlations could be quite consistent with a correct model. Is there a suitable model for the detection bias?